# Caroufredsel width 0 despite specifying width in config

Tags: caroufredsel

I'm working with a basic Caroufredsel setup with a main image up top, and thumbnails below. My issue is getting the thumbnails to show at the right size whether there's just one, two, or more. I've got it so that it's almost there, with one remaining weird issue.

When the div is shown, the thumbnails don't appear; with the debugger I can see that the caroufredsel_wrapper class has a width of 0, even though I've tried setting it explicitly to 330 in the config. If I resize the browser, then it "wakes up" and the width gets set correctly. I haven't been able to figure out what's causing this.

The config:

```
$('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
  responsive: true,
  circular: false,
  infinite: false,
  width: 330,
  height: 65,
  auto: false,
  items: {
    width       : "auto",
    height      : "50%",
    visible     : {
      min         : 4,
      max         : 5
    }
  }
});
```

Earlier, I had no height/width specified for the carousel, and explicit "width: 150, height: 75" for the items. Everything was rendered as expected, but the width of the items was actually variable so the images were stretched if only 1 or 2 thumbnails were present. Why the explicit item height/width was ignored also remains a mystery.

Any suggestions would be fantastic; it's driving me nuts.

Comment: I may have found the answer myself, although it doesn't seem like the best answer. Maybe it'll help someone else, anyway. After the carousel is initialized, it looks like calling "updateSizes" gets it to figure out the correct width: $("#thumbs").trigger("updateSizes");

Answer (score 1):

The above comment is correct. If you put the carousel in a hidden div that you later reveal by tabs it will make all the heights and widths to be zero so it will seem like caroufredsel is hidden.

You can attach the update sizes trigger to the tab click. E.g.

```
$j("ul.tabs a[href=#tab2]").click( function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#thumbs").trigger('updateSizes'); 
            }, 200);
        });
```

The delay ensures the container is displayed before updateSizes triggers.